# Known measure to calculate how much a group affected the global average

Tags: statistical-significance, sample, mean

I'm not a statistical expert but I guess that there's a known measure to calculate which group affects the global average.

**Example:** consider 3 groups:

```
A - avg 80 with 100 samples
B - avg 90 with 1 sample
C - avg 0 with 1 sample
```

The overall average would be: $(8000 + 90 + 0) / 102 = 79.3$

$A$ should be the most affected group, then $C$ and last comes $B$.

In this scenario, I could calculate the difference between the average with vs. without the group for each group and get the results I wanted.

E.g. without group $A$ the average will be 45 (almost 35), without group $C$ the average will be 80.099 (~1.7), and without group $B$ the average will be 79.2 (~1.1).

But then if I would have another group $D$, which looks like group $A$, (average 80 100 samples) it dramatically drops Group $A$ and Group $B$ to affect like Group $C$.

**Question:**
Is this is a good formula? Is there any known formula for that (something with standard deviation, mean, *et cetera*$\dots$)?

Comment: [Leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)), considered by category perhaps?

Comment: @EngrStudent, Thanks, interesting but what I'm searching is not related to regression. I want to sort the groups by how much they affected the overall average. My formula looks a bit cumbersome.